# Does the existence of Prawn weapons suggest other hostile races in the District 9 universe?

Tags: district-9

It seems established that the Prawns are a hive-mind type of society so I would think they would be cohesive enough that there wouldn't be many internal conflicts, at least those that would require violence to resolve. I would also presume that if the hive-mind structure were to fracture as it did in the movie you wouldn't want there to be such destructive weaponry around to be used by individuals.

Given that the weapons were pretty darn destructive why else would you bring them on a interstellar voyage? Wouldn't that be a bit like Earth astronauts bringing a grenade launcher to the Moon?

Comment: You say that, but earth cosmonauts did bring [guns in the Soyuz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TP-82)

Comment: This also assumes that all prawns that have ever existed are in the same hive mind. Now, I haven't seen the movie since it was in theaters, but I wouldn't bet against there being multiple 'colonies' of prawn (if not on Earth, then on their home planet).

Comment: You can't just call aliens *Prawns*, that a really offensive anti-Poleepkwa slur.

Comment: @CBredlow As I understand it, that was so that in case they landed in Siberia they could fend off Polar Bears until rescue arrived.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - The *Prawns* didn't mind.

Comment: Well, you're coming to explore and potentially colonise a world that has life similar to yours. Are you seriously not going to bring scout vehicles? Are you not going to give them weapons to defend themselves against local fauna (regardless of whether you expect them to be intelligent or not?). Wild animals are quite dangerous, you know :)

Comment: "Christopher" and his son don't appear to have hive-minds. They are extremely intelligent and independent thinkers and take some pains to conceal the fact. I don't think the prawns are being completely honest with us.

Comment: @Luaan Yep. Dinosaurs definitely need weapons used against them...

Comment: Imagine if they had been dumped over Austrailia.  The weapons might have allowed them to survive the things there that just wants to kill everything.

Comment: @TheMathemagician True. It might be that they *can* be dominated by a hive-mind, but when the control is lost, they are actually capable of independent intelligent operation. Of course, if they lived their whole life under direct control, they might not be in the best shape to take care of their interstellar spaceship regardless of their raw intelligence :)

Comment: @SGR and it actually happened. The unplanned landing in the middle of nowhere and having to wait for rescue, that is. I don't think they had to fend off any wildlife, as it happened, but it was distinctly possible.

Comment: @TheMathemagician - This was explicitly covered by the director's interview below. Christopher has become a leadership caste prawn because of the absence of other leadership caste prawns. Without a directing mind they're argumentative, undirected and prone to poor decision-making.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're heading into a situation where you *know* there are no hostile forces--as we did with going to the Moon--then why bother taking weapons? All they would do is add mass to the launch vehicle and be a useless encumbrance for the astronauts.

The situations where you take weapons are two in number:

- When you *know* that there are hostile forces
- When you *don't know* what's there.

Unfortunately, the possible existence of these situations means that we don't know if there are other alien races out there in the District 9 universe. The existence of such races was unimportant to the plot, therefore the matter is not even discussed.

Comment: Valorum answered the question I should have asked. This answers the question that I actually asked.

Comment: @Cradle2theGabe, as long as you got the answers or answers that you *needed*, I'm a happy camper. :)

Comment: The ship in District 9 is *massive*, city sized, and capable of hovering for months. It doesn't appear to use traditional propulsion technology. I don't think they care about a little extra mass.

Comment: @Schwern Oh, to be sure--I'm extrapolating from our technology.

Comment: Situation 3: You really like weapons.

Comment: @OrangeDog, I might fall into that third category. Maybe. :D

Comment: @Schwern makes the most salient point that mass limits may apply far less with the right tech.

Comment: Situation 4:  You're unsure whether or not your technology is fit for purpose, and want to give your explorers some extra insurance against the possibility of a slow, agonizing death.

Comment: @OrangeDog So you're saying the aliens are the interstellar equivalent of Open Carry advocates? ;)

Comment: Situation 3: Your ship has such a large compliment of crew/passengers that you need/want weapons to maintain order and control. (there were hundreds, if not thousands, of starving aliens when they cut the ship open). I do not know if any has even ever guessed at the intended number of personnel for that ship, but it could be astronomically bigger than the medium sized community we see years latter.

Answer (score 21):

According to an interview that the film's director (Neil Blomkamp) did for Io9.com, there are **definitely other life-forms out there**, aside than the Prawns and the humans.

> *The other thing is that the ship was meant to clip together with other
> ships. So there's, like, vast amounts of resources that they're
> bringing to the parent planet. **And the ship, when the army generals or
> the queen of that particular ship died off by some sort of virus or
> bacteria that they picked up on some other planet, that killed them
> off.***
>
> *And it didn't effect these sort of resilient, hardy sort of drone
> workers. Then the technology is usually the thing that they relied on
> to save them, but in this case it sort of screwed them because it
> brought them to a planet that kind of treated them pretty badly, but
> it was the ship that realized that, unless it gets to a life
> sustaining planet everything is going to die, which is a cool idea. So
> the ship just autopilots to the closest one in the Goldilocks band,
> and it's our planet and then pulls up and hits the brakes.*
>
> <sub><sup>[District 9's Director Tells Us All About His Alien Back Story](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5331799/district-9s-director-tells-us-all-about-his-alien-back-story)</sup></sub>

Obviously bacteria don't need to be kept at bay with guns and mech-suits, but the simple fact that single-celled organisms can be found in our galaxy would strongly imply that there are other higher lifeforms as well.

---

As regards the possibility that the weapons are for use ***against their own kind***, that seems extremely unlikely.

> *The hive mind [concept] is the most important thing to me, because **I love the idea of a civilization that can build all of that technology and then, at the same time, just have a massive population that was just drones that needed direction, and were absolutely incapable of building that stuff on their own.** I found that to be a really interesting concept. Also, it sort of explains why they don't turn on the humans. Individually, they may be feeling oppressed, but they don't have it together enough to form a resistance and back one another. So I found that really interesting.*

Comment: I'm realizing that I should have asked my question differently because this answer is really what I was getting at even though this is word of god rather than inferences from the movie itself. I had thought the weapons angle was the best way to entertain the concept.

Comment: I assume those spelling errors in the quotes are in the original, but they're really jarring.

Comment: @Glen - it's a transcript so I've no compunction  about correcting it :-)

Answer (score 6):

> *Wouldn't that be a bit like Earth astronauts bringing a grenade launcher to the Moon?*

It could be like Europeans bringing guns and cannon to the New World.

Our trip to the Moon was just to see if we could do it. It pushed the edges of our technology. Everything had to be stripped down to make it happen. And we knew there were no little green men there (or Soviets).

In contrast the ship in District 9 is enormous. City sized. And it can float indifferently for months. Its hull is so thick it takes considerable effort to cut through. They've obviously been a space-faring civilization some time. They're not too concerned about weight. It's not a lunar lander getting three people to the Moon and back, it's a [Galleon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galleon) taking a small city.

What was the purpose of that ship? We don't know. But if it had the intent of exploring or gathering resources, those weapons could be for the inhabitants. We're the natives who get gunned down.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given that their weapons were built in such a way that you had to be a Prawn to use them suggests that their weapons were at risk of being used by some other tool-using species – else why add such technology? And unless they were built specifically with the intention of coming to Earth, it suggests that this other species isn't us humans.

Answer (score 1):

Having a hive-mind structure does not imply that the weapons are for outsiders.  Odds are, there is more than one hive - and take it from bees and ants, different hives generally don't 'play nice' with each other.

Comment: They *do* seem to have one hive, though.

Comment: Also, is [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/72240/pmar) also you? If you happen to have made two accounts, you can merge them by following this instructions [here.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a species on Earth that does not fight with other members/groups of it's own kind? Can a species evolve and totally dominate a world without developing weapons of some sort?

The answers to both of these are no, therefor, the Prawn having weapons do not imply there are other hostile species out there.

Comment: In regard to your second question I think they could given the hive-mind nature of their species.

Comment: @Cradle2theGabe ant hives have extensive wars with each other. Unless there has only ever been one hive then war seems likely

Comment: @user20310 I take your point but I'm really asking why weapons would be brought on a space voyage more so than why weapons would exist at all.

Comment: @Cradle2theGabe I don't see that there needs to be an explanation for bringing weapons into space. Even if nothing is hostile you still might them for hunting or whatever.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that conflict might be a prerequisite to the kind of intelligence required for a technological civilization. To get the kind of massive, unbridled progress humans had, you need to always be in some sort of conflict with someone as smart as you are - a positive feedback loops that keeps requiring you to be smarter and smarter. This happens with pretty much every single animal on Earth to an extent - even grazers fight for their pastures. It might be that you'd be able to have that sort of competion with a different species as well, but it's certainly simplest with just one.

Comment: You don't develop the ability to 'species-code' weapons unless you're using them against something intelligent enough to use them against you.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a very simple possibility that the thing you think as a weapon can actually be a tool. Primarily used for cleaning debris, or welding, or protecting from predators, or whatever. 
But used as a weapon when such a need arises.

Comment: I was thinking of making that argument myself, but some of the Prawn tech in District 9 is definitely militarized and should be considered a weapon first and foremost.

Comment: Agree with Danikov. Though I recall there was some sort of gravity gun, and the mech seemed to have some kind of similar capabilities which could be used in that respect.